# Where to post question about KML?

Tags: support, status-completed

I have been having a problem with a KML file and I'm not sure where to ask for input.  I am creating the KML using the "Layer to KML" tool in ArcMap, but I get an error message when I try to open it in Google Earth.

Is the Geographic Information Systems an appropriate place to ask about this (because of the ArcMap component), or is there another board that would be more appropriate (because of the Google Earth component)?

Comment: On the Main Site GIS.SE http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask with the tags KML and arcgis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Questions about ArcGIS for Desktop, KML and/or Google Earth would all seem to be on topic for GIS Stack Exchange so I recommend that you post your Question.

Comment: I think we mostly all agree. However, see the discussion at http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3490/where-should-google-earth-api-questions-really-be -- I think there is still an *unsolved* problem regarding GE in that Google and SO are operating under the assumption that GE questions belong at SO.

Comment: But the Tool here is ArcGIS not Google Earth but the format it uses. Google Earth is a distributed GIS many companies use if 'freely' with their own KML data for visual analysis

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I had seen some questions like the one martin f posted so I wasn't sure. Thanks.

Comment: @martinf I do not see a problem with Questions being on topic for more than one SE/SO site - as long as asker posts Question to only one, and asks for it to be migrated if he/she  "decides to back another horse" later.

Comment: @Mapperz - Sorry for "hijacking" this discussion. I should have just added my link to the related Q and stopped there. (Maybe i'll find another way of resurrecting *my* issue.)